# IONIC: the app is being frozen or the display is being unorganized

Tags: android, css, ios, angular, ionic-framework

I am facing a problem when using the app this issue is like a chance to replicate when opening the app many times. The issue is happening on ios but on android, it works perfectly fine.

here are the reproduced steps

1. Open the app many times
2. Chances to replicate the issue

Here is the attachment that happens on ios [image: ios screen]

Comment: have you tried to inspect it with safari in macos to see if there are any console logs that may help?

Comment: I tried to inspect on safari but didn't help.